# auto update from the appstore and playmarket does not work

Tags: android, ios

Problem. After the app appears in the AppStore and PlayMarket on the third day, the user still has the previous version of the app installed.

All settings for automatic updates are enabled, as other apps are generally updated.

Research. How can we speed up auto-update without forcing the user to do it when entering the app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].